# sed command fails when running via terraform local exec in linux

Tags: linux, sed, terraform

I am trying to run the below sed command using terraform local_exec to replace the account id in a deployment yaml file.I am running it in ubuntu ec2 machine

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    command = <<EOT
      sed -i 's/\(image: \)[^.]*\(\.dkr\.\)/\1${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}\2/' deployment/java-apps/deployment.yaml
    EOT
  }
```

But it fails with the following error:
`No such file or directory Output: sed: can't read deployment/java-apps/deployment.yaml`

When I run it manually the command it can find the file and it replaces the value. But when its executed via terraform it fails. It even works when I execute the same terraform script using git bash in my windows machine. But in the ubuntu linux machine I receive the error.

What do I need to change to make it run via terraform?

Comment: Terraform isn't aware of the relative path. Try with a `./` or something like `${path.root}` or `${path.module}`.

Comment: I tried with both ./ and ${path.root}, still I receive the same error. `(local-exec): sed: can't read ./deployment/java-apps/deployment.yaml `.

Comment: Did you try changing your command to `pwd` to verify where you think the command is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check newlines of all your terraform files - they should be Unix newlines (`\n`), not Windows (`\r\n`).

This could be a possible cause of your problem, since you mentioned Windows machine and your command happens to contain a newline in a heredoc-string in your yaml.

With Windows's newline, you'll see something like this when you run your command via terraform in Linux:

```
(local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-c" "      sed -i 's/test/text/' deployment/java-apps/deployment.yaml\r\n"]
```

Note the `deployment/java-apps/deployment.yaml\r\n` - that `\r` will be treated as part of a filename, giving you error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, it was because of \r\n being read by Linux. I used `sed -i 's/\r//g' <file name>` command to remove the \r and its now working.